# Laravel email send category

Tags: php, laravel, email

How I can send email with laravel and so that it falls into the category alerts on gmail?

[image]

Code:

```
Mail::send('emails.mailExample', $user, function($message) use ($user) {
    $message->to($user->email);
    $message->subject('E-Mail Example');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Labels/Categories are an internal Gmail mechanism and as such not part of the email protocol or anything of the like. Gmail labels incoming emails based on user-defined filters, e.g. emails coming from a certain address or containing certain words or phrases.

If you want to label certain emails with certain tags, then you need to create the rules in your GMail, and then send out emails following these rules.

For instance, you could create a rule applying for the tag 'work' to every email coming from Laravel's email address with the word [work] in the title, and then send emails like that.

Answer (score 0):

Trying Help You 
First you must config your mail go to Config/mail.php
and add this after driver

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smtp'),
'stream' => [
    'ssl' => [
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => true,
    ],
],
```

Second Go to you .env file change this to your host details list try with gmail one

MAIL_DRIVER=smtp

MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com

MAIL_PORT=587

MAIL_USERNAME=yourgmailMail@gmail.com

MAIL_PASSWORD=yourpassword

MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls

Third go to your Controller that you will make send mail function in lists Assume its name is SendMassEmailController
[This is the Whole Controller](https://codepad.co/snippet/zz6A9k3p)

last thing is the route
go to web.php

```
Route::post('/SendMassEmail','SendMassEmailController@SendMassEmail');
```

Finally Good Luck and Have Fun

Comment: I have smtp on my site